# Writing to CSV in Python - equivalent code

Tags: python, pandas, csv

As per [this tutorial](http://pbpython.com/excel-diff-pandas.html), I want to write to a csv file. What would the equivalent code be for the following block?

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter("my-diff-2.xlsx")
diff_output.to_excel(writer,"changed")
removed_accounts.to_excel(writer,"removed",index=False,columns=["account number", "name","street","city","state","postal code"])
added_accounts.to_excel(writer,"added",index=False,columns=["account number", "name","street","city","state","postal code"])
writer.save()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This block write 3 DataFrames to 3 sheets in one excel file. But csv file has no sheets. So simplier solution is write each `DataFrame` separately to 3 `csv`:

```
diff_output.to_csv('file1.csv', index=False)
removed_accounts.to_csv('file2.csv', index=False)
added_accounts.to_csv('file3.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Ah, yes. I didn't account for the multiple sheets in Excel. Thanks!

That's what was stumping me. Feel pretty stupid now.

Comment: Dont worry, you missed it only ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
import csv 
myData = [["first_name", "second_name", "Grade"], 
        ['Alex', 'Brian', 'A'], 
        ['Tom', 'Smith', 'B']]

myFile = open('example2.csv', 'w')
with myFile:
    writer = csv.writer(myFile)
    writer.writerows(myData)

print("Writing complete")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
with open("my-diff-2.csv","w+") as f:
   writes = csv.writer(f)
   writes.writerow(["account number", "name","street","city","state","postal code"]) #this is header
   for lines in [["a","b"]]: # here it should be list of list
       writes.writerow(lines) # writing the data in row-wise
```